# Number of ways of choosing $l$ numbers out $1,...,m$ and place them in $l$ positions out of $N$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider $1,...,N$ positions and let $l\leq m$ and $l\leq N$. How many ways of choosing $ l$ numbers out of $m$ and placing them in $l$ positions out of $N$ does exist if there has to be always one number at position 1 and one at position 2? Further it is not allowed that more than one number is distributed to each position.  My idea is as follows.

Choosing $l$ out of $\{1,...,m\}$ is bounded by $m^l$

Distributing $l-2$ numbers to $N-2$ positions (as two numbers must be on position 1 and position 2)is bounded by: $(N-2) \cdot (N-2-1) \cdot...\cdot (N-2-l+2+1) \leq N^{l-2}$

So the total number of ways is bounded by: $ m^l * N^{l-2}$. I dont think its correct because I dont include the fixing of 2 numbers at position 1 and 2. But I dont know how to handle this add on.

Comment: When choosing the $l$ numbers out of $\{1,\dots,m\}$, are you allowing them to repeat or must they be distinct.  There is a very easy closed form solution if they are not allowed to repeat.  You seem to be using bounds a lot instead of trying to pursue exact amounts, is there a reason why?  For example, instead of using $\leq N^{l-2}$, you could use the exact amount $(N-2)\frac{l-2}{~}$ using falling factorial notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. We allow them to repeat so possibly one could always choose the same number. The reason is that I dont have to pursue exact amounts I just need a good bound. Do you see any mistakes? Maybe the fixing of position 1 and 2 can be handled by adding the product $l * (l-1)$.

Comment: Yes, you are missing the $l\cdot (l-1)$ term to account for specifically which are occupying positions $1$ and $2$, though if it so happens that there are repeats this will be too large.  In the case that repeats weren't allowed it would be exactly $\binom{m}{l}\cdot l\cdot (l-1)\cdot (N-2)\frac{l-2}{~}$.  With repeats allowed and you just looking for an easily proven upper bound, $m^ll^2N^l$ is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.